# Can I delete a Kafka Partition version 0.10.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka, partition

We have a requirement that demands to delete/purge data for any given partition within a topic. I am using Kafka 0.10.0.1. Is there any way I can delete entire partition content on demand? If yes then how. I see that we can use log compaction to post a null message for a key and delete it but other than that is there any way to achieve deletion?

Answer (score 3):

Kafka does not currently support reducing the number of partitions for a topic, so no out-of-box tool is offered to be used to remove a partition directly.

Comment: The original question is actually asking "Can I delete the data for an individual partition".  E.g. if I have produced data to partitions 0 and 1, can I delete all the *data* in just partition 1 and reset its offset back to 0.